# What is this error and how do I fix it? error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Here is my code and this is the first time I've gotten an error like this while C coding so I don't know what the problem is. I've tried to fix it by using different syntaxes with the same purpose but still no luck. Would appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main
{
    FILE * fp1;
    char record[49];
    //size_t len = 0;
    //ssize_t linelen;
    int id[1000];
    char name[1000][50];
    double scores[1000][5];
    double grade[1000];


    fp1 = fopen"stud.txt","r";
    if fp1==NULL
    exitEXITFAILURE;
char * field;
int index=0;
int linelen=49;
while fgets(record,linelen,fp1!=NULL )
    {
        if feof(fp1) break;
        //printf"Readalineoflength;
        //printf";
        field = strtokrecord,"$";
        int i=0, fieldcount=1;
        whilefield!=NULL
        {

            if fieldcount==1
        {
            id[index]=atoifield;
            }
            if fieldcount==2
        {
            strcpyname[index],field;
            }
            if fieldcount>2
        {
            scores[index][i]=strtodfield,NULL;
                i++;

            }

            strcpyfield,"";
            field = strtokNULL,"$";
            fieldcount++;

        }//while field

        grade[index]=scores[index][0]*0.15+scores[index][1]*0.15+scores[index][2]*0.25+scores[index][3]*0.10+scores[index][4]*0.35;
        if grade([index]!=0)
            printf("\nGrade:");

            index++;
    }  //while not eof

    fclosefp1;
    if record
    freerecord;
exitEXITSUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the error is in the 5th line of code where the first "{" is written, and the error that comes up on my compiler is:

error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token

Comment: Write int main( void ) instead of int main

Comment: I think you forgot the braces here: `if fp1==NULL` and `whilefield!=NULL`

Comment: The code looks as if all braces were removed. For all conditions, function calls, parameter lists...

Comment: If that is the first time you get such an error, does this imply that you have already written code that compiles?

Comment: Seriously, if you can't find any problems in this code, you cannot possibly have studied a single chapter of any beginner learning material.

Answer (score 1):

The function main without parameters is declared like

```
int main( void )
{
    //...
```

However you wrote

```
int main
{
    //...
```

So the compiler considers this line

```
int main
```

as a declaration of a variable with the name main where a semicolon is forgotten.

There are another syntax errors as for example in this statement

```
fp1 = fopen"stud.txt","r";
```

You have to enclose the arguments in parentheses.

```
fp1 = fopen( "stud.txt","r" );
```

Or this if statement

```
if fp1==NULL
```

is syntactically incorrect. And so on.

So read compiler errors and update your code accordingly.